# Creating Google Apps account for a client?

Tags: google-workspace

I have been in a web development business for about 15 years now. At one point we have hosted about 150 sites as a reseller, but now the number shrunk to about 40 - we have moved to servicing fewer larger clients than a lot of smaller ones.

We are now also moving to hosting websites only and have client email go through Google Apps. For a medium size organization that means that we have to do all the setup ourselves,and serve as a temporary IT department. I am a bit confused on how to create Google Apps account for a third party - what to enter as a current email address, what to do with the billing info and how to remove myself from that client Google Apps space once we set up all the email and make sure email accounts are functional.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are handing these things off, I would work with a representative of each client to set up the Google Apps accounts.  You want a client rep to be the account owner and to also provide the billing information.

Once those initial steps are complete, the client creates you as an admin user with the ability to manage other users.  You then complete the setup and migration.  When done, interface with the client representative again to remove your admin account.

Comment: Actually, I am wondering if I should set up an email account such as admin@client_website.com and do all the work from there and then just hand over the access. We also apparently can do a 30 day trial, so the billing info can be entered at a later stage. I will try that first. 

This is going to be quite a bit faster than spending an hour training someone to set up a Google Apps account.

Comment: @Natalia The only possible issue with that approach is that you pay per account with Google Apps (unless this is * For Education or * For Non-Profits) so a burner account like admin@ has to be changed to be something real in order to avoid the extra fees. I also don't like knowing the master password for an account and prefer to have them set me up with my own (my little contribution teaching non-tech people about account security best practices). These are not deal-breaking objections to your proposed path though.

Comment: @JCL1178 - I read Natalia's comment to be that she plans to create a permanent account using an admin@ email address from her client's domain. After she's done with her work, she'll hand over the account to the client. Why did you call this a burner account, and why did you say it has to be changed to be something real? I just want to understand your comment better in case I'm missing something.